# Bug with aligning div to center horizontal

Tags: html, css, alignment, height

I tried to center the div by using this way:
div height is : 35.3em
margin-top : calc(50% - (35.3em / 2))

The bug happens when i play with the width of the browser, The div somehow change his horizontal position

The URL of my site : http://cherry-rocks.herokuapp.com

Comment: If you are willing to use flexbox, you can set the parent div with "display: flex" and the children with "margin: auto" for perfect centering all the time.

Comment: Thanks! worked for me

Comment: Awesome! :) I also posted this as a real answer, so you can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you use relative positioning, you can also use top instead of margin-top to explicitly position the element to the center. Use `top: calc(50% - (35.3em / 2))` instead of margin-top or `display: flex` on the parent and `margin: auto` on the child, if you are willing to use flexbox.